# Which of my Heroku add-ons have a pending forced upgrade?

Tags: heroku, heroku-addon

I didn't think Heroku ever did forced upgrades but according to this page regarding heroku-redis:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/2541

> On April 30, 2023, the deprecated versions will become unavailable for provisioning and we’ll perform forced upgrades after May 30, 2023.

Well now I find myself wondering how many other add-ons are ticking time bombs!

I'm consulting with a client on some Heroku maintenance so don't have access to the history of emails that Heroku tends to send about these things.

Is there a master list of upcoming forced upgrades or a way to find out, per addon, if there's an upcoming forced upgrade.

Thanks!